# Make wordpress back to http from https

Tags: php, wordpress, http, https

I have wordpress site which was working correctly on apache site before.

```
https://example.com -> (port 443) -> apache server
```

However now I installed nginx for reverse proxy.

```
https://example.com -> (port 443) -> nginx ->(port 8080) -> apache
```

So now, when accesing wordpress site, there comes the error like this below

```
The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS
```

I guess it is because of some files loaded from wordpress does not accept `HTTP`

How can I solve this? is there any relevant setting in wordpress ?

I can understand the server setting , but wordpress is blackbox for me.

Comment: This is for sure that some content or URL is being loaded with HTTP instead of HTTPS, what you can do is find and replace all "http://" and replace it with "https://" in your database with a simple DB query or WP CLI if you have installed.

Comment: Forgot one more thing, can you also check that you are using the HTTPS version of your URLs in Settings → General → Site Address and WordPress Address? This could cause also the issue.

Comment: which url has been blocked? check DevTools.

Comment: If you check using chromes developer tools you will see that some of your javascript files are loaded over http://example.com . This needs to be fixed in code. You should include any external javascript over https protocol to get rid of that warning.

Answer (score 0):

Check your page source and you must be having some external javascript files served over http like

```
<script src="http://example.com/bla/bla/somefile.js">
```

This needs to be served over https, like ...

```
<script src="https://example.com/bla/bla/somefile.js">
```

If you check using chromes developer tool you will find out easily which of your javascript files are loaded over example.com . This needs to be fixed in code. You should include any external javascript over https protocol to get rid of that warning.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can take HTTP/S back with a few simple SQLs:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://example.com', 'https://example.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://example.com', 'https://example.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://example.com', 'https://example.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, 'http://example.com','https://example.com');
```

But be careful, not all scripts support the HTTP protocol, as already mentioned.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).